# Why do some hotels in Mexico charge more when there's a child?

Tags: hotels, children, mexico, price

Why do hotel charge more when there is one adult and a child, than a double adult occupancy when you are traveling to Mexico.

Comment: I also see this, I made tentative bookings at Gran Hotel Ciudad de Mexico and Las Alcobas.

Comment: @ida can you give an example of where this happened to you?